# Angular 2.0 ,no me muestra datos correctos cuando elimino

Tags: angularjs-2.0

cuadro.component.ts

Tengo un problema,estoy tratando de eliminar un dato

```
<ul>
        <li *ngFor="let user of users">
            <p @heroState='user.state' (click)="user.toggleState()">{{user.name}}</p> 
            <p>{{user.state}}</p>
            <button (click)="remove(user)"> Eliminar </button>
        </li>
    </ul>

export class CuadroComponent {
    @Input() users:EjemploService;
    @Output() evento=new EventEmitter();
...


}
```

//app.component

```
    selector: 'my-app',
template: `Prueba angular2.0</h1>
    <p>Probando cuadro</p>
<button [disabled]="!users.canAdd()" (click)="users.addActive()">Añadir Activo</button>
<button [disabled]="!users.canAdd()" (click)="users.addActive()" >Añadir Inactivo</button>
<button [disabled]="!users.canRemove()" (click)="users.remove()" >Remover </button>
<cuadro [users]=users (evento)="evento($event)"></cuadro>
`,
```

ejemplo.service.ts

```
remove(user:User=null){
    console.log("USER A REMOVER==",user)
    if(user==null){
    this.items.splice(this.items.length-1,1);
    }
    else{
    this.items=this.items.filter(u=>u!=user);
    }
    console.log("LISTA FINAL",this.items)
    this.items.forEach(function(x,y){
    console.log(x,y);
    })
    }
```

Me muestra una lista de usuarios ,al costado de c/u hay un boton , cuando presiono me elimina ese usuario , el detalle esta que me elimina mal
ejemplo:
1
2
3
4

elimino el segundo y me elimina toda la tira de abajo , quedando.
1

he puesto el codigo concerniente a a esas partes,espero su ayuda, en cuanto a los usuarios que quedan , he puesto varios logs y veo que cuando elimino el usuario n , si me retorna todos los usuarios que deberian ir , pero estos no se muestran , sino solo los que estaban arriba del que elimine.

Como ven antes de eliminar.
[image: Como se ve antes de eliminar]//

[image: Como ven si me retorna los usuarios que deberian quedar]

Luego de eliminar , al costado en un console ,me muestran los usuarios que quedan, pero estos no se reflejan en la directiva.

Comment: ¿Ya solucionaste el problema?

Answer (score 0):

Remueve el usuario por medio del **indice** del arreglo.

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let user of users; let i of index">
        <p @heroState='user.state' (click)="user.toggleState()">{{user.name}}</p> 
        <p>{{user.state}}</p>
        <button (click)="remove(i)"> Eliminar </button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Y tu función en el **service**

```
remove(index){
    this.users.splice(index, 1);
}
```

Si remueves por el **indice** del arreglo te seguirá mostrando los usuarios en la lista sin afectar el orden.

Espero te funcione.